# How do I determine what's causing "Styles Invalidated" in iOS Safari?

Tags: css, angularjs, safari, mobile-safari, angular-material

I'm chasing down a performance issue when scrolling on iOS. On both `touchstart` and `touchend`, Safari is invalidating and then recalculating styles, which results in a slight delay before scrolling responds. Safari's tools have an "initiator" column, but it is blank in my tests.

I've tried:

- Applying either `will-change: transform;` or `transform: translateZ(0);` on the scrolling element. This helped immensely on Chrome, but does nothing for iOS Safari. The profiler still reports that styles are being recalculated.
- Removing all elements from the DOM that have `position: fixed;`
- Inspecting each line of Javascript (which was just jQuery and Angular core code in my tests) reported by the profiler to see if they are in [Paul Irish's list of things that force layout/reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a)
- To reproduce it on Android so I could use Chrome's stellar dev tools, without success. The issue only affects iOS Safari, which can only be debugged from desktop Safari.

How can I determine what is causing my styles to be invalidated in iOS Safari?

[image: Javascript timelines]
[image: Layout timelines]

Comment: This is a known "issue" in iOS, see here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away. Use Fastclick.js to help alleviate, and I think newer versions of iOS after 8 remove this click delay "feature". Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm not sure that's the same. Scrolling responds faster on pages with a simpler DOM structure for me, it's not a static delay. I'm certain that it's related to style invalidating.

Comment: Faced the same issue, and the only way which worked for was to look through every animated stuff on a single page and try disabling it and check whether it helped. In my case the reflow was caused by "animated='true'" parameter of <ion-searchbar> component from ionic.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me when I debugged a similar issue.

1. Get the start time of the event you want to look into. Should be on the second to last column when in the view from your screenshot.
2. Click on the tab next to the "Events" tab, named "Frames".
3. Look for the frame with the closest matching start time. ( Sometimes it's not exact )
4. Expanding the frame lets you see the events that happened right before/after the event you're looking into. On the last column "Location" you can see where the problem was caused. If it's filled in, you can click on the right arrow to see the line that caused it. **BUT it doesn't always have something in the column.** I have to then look at the previous events to try to figure out what the problem is.

It's not perfect, but I've been able to debug the problems I've ran into with this method. Hope this helps!

Comment: Nothing shows up in the `Location` column for _any_ of my paint frames 